# Grails withCriteria If Statements?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

Is it possible to use If statements within a withCriteria block? I am trying to do the following:

```
allInfo = Scholarship.withCriteria {
  //eq('gpa', gpa)
  if (year != "All" || year != null) {
    println "grades"
    grades {
      idEq year
    }
  }
  if (county != "All" || county != null) {
    println "county"
    scholarshipCounties {
        eq('county.id', county)
    }
  }
  if (major != "All" || major != null) {
    println "major"
    majors {
      idEq major
    }
  }
  if (activity != "All" || activity != null) {
    println "activity"
    activities {
        idEq activity
    }
  }
  eq('specialTypeInd', special)
  eq('activeInd', "A")
  order("name", "asc")
}
```

year, county, major, and activity all are "All" when I am testing currently. I also already made sure they were Strings and not something else. Obviously It is printing out grades, county, etc when It shouldnt even be getting inside those if statements. So what is the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Boolean logic looks faulty - a test like

```
if (year != "All" || year != null)
```

will *always* evaluate to `true` for *any* value of `year` - if `year` is null then it is not "All" and vice versa.  If you want the block to fire for any non-null `year` value except "All" then it needs to be `&&` instead of `||`.

Comment: This explains where my mistake with my thinking was.